# How to login successfully?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
     <html>
   <head>
    <style>
  .error {
 color:red;
   }

  .button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
   border: none;
    color: white;
 padding: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
     }
  .div1 {
background-color: #f2f2f2;
margin-top: -19px;
margin-bottom: -25px;
margin-left: -19px; 
  }

 .copy {
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 6px 20px;
  border-style: ridge;
   }

  .copy1{
 border-radius: 4px;
 padding: 6px 28px;
 border-style: ridge;
   }

    .copy2{
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px 2px;

  }
   </style>
  </head>
   <body>  

  <?php
   // define variables and set to empty values
   include_once 'connect.php';
  $nameErr = $emailErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $DateOfBirthErr = 
    $departmentErr = $ageErr = "";
    $name = $email = $username = $password = $DateOfBirth = $department = 
   $age = "";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
       }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
       } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
       }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
     $usernameErr = "Username is required";
      } else {
     $username = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$username)) {
   $usernameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
       }
       }

     if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passwordErr = "Password is required";
    } else {
     $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  // check weather password is alphanumeric
    if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[0-9A-Za-z!@#$%]{6,}$/', 
  $password))
    {
$passwordErr = "Password must be alphanumeric and atleast 6 characters 
   long!";
   }
  }

    if (empty($_POST["Date_of_birth"])) {
    $DateOfBirthErr = "Date Of Birth is required";
   } else {
  $DateOfBirth = test_input($_POST["Date_of_birth"]);
    }

   if (empty($_POST["department"])) {
    $departmentErr = "Department is required";
   } else {
   $department = test_input($_POST["department"]);
     }

   if (empty($_POST["age"])) {
        $ageErr = "Age is required";
      } else {
        $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
  }

   if($nameErr == "" && $emailErr == "" && $usernameErr == "" && 
  $passwordErr == "")
    { 
  $check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]'";
     $rs = mysqli_query($mysqli,$check);
  $da = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
 if($da[0] > 0) {
 echo "Username Already in Exists<br/>";
 }

   else
{
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users(`id`,`username`, `password`, `email` , 
    `name` , `Date_of_birth` , `department` ,`age`)
         VALUES ('','".$username."', '".$hashed_password."', '".$email."' , 
 '".$name."' , '".$DateOfBirth."' , '".$department."' , '".$age."')";

    if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
    echo "Registered successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
    } 
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
   }
  }

  }

   function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
   }
   ?>

  <div style="padding-left: 250px" class="div1">
  <h2 style="color:#009999">Registration Form :</h2>
  <p><span class="error">All fields are required </span></p>
  <form method="post" action="">  
    <span style="color:#0099ff">Name: </span>
  <input type="text" name="name" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 52px">
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
 <span style="color:#0099ff"> E-mail: </span>
 <input type="text" name="email" class= "copy" style="margin-left: 48px">
 <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
 <br><br>
  <span style="color:#0099ff"> Username: </span>
 <input type="text" name="username"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:26px">
   <span class="error"> <?php echo $usernameErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
  <span style="color:#0099ff"> Password: </span>
    <input type="password" name="password"  class= "copy" style="margin- 
    left:30px">
  <span class="error"> <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
   <span style="color:#0099ff"> Date Of Birth : </span>
      <input type="date" class= "copy1" name="Date_of_birth">
      <span class="error"> <?php echo $DateOfBirthErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
 <span style="color:#0099ff">  Age : </span>
    <input type="number" name="age"  class= "copy" style="margin-left:62px">
    <span class="error"> <?php echo $ageErr;?></span>
      <br><br>
    <span style="color:#0099ff">  Department : </span>
 <select name="department"  class= "copy2" style="margin-left:14px">
   <option value="EE">Electrical & Electronics</option>
  <option value="EC">Electronics & Communication</option>
  <option value="ME">Mechanical</option>
  <option value="CS">Computer Science</option>
  <option value="CV">Civil</option>
    <option value="IS">Information Science</option>
   </select>
 <span class="error"> <?php echo $departmentErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
 <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Register">  
 <p style="color:black">Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login</a>. 
 </p>
    </form>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

login.php

```
 <?php
   include_once 'connect.php';
 session_start();

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   // username and password sent from form 

   $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
   $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = 
  '$mypassword'";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active = $row['active'];

    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

    if($count == 1) {
     session_register("myusername");
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

     header("location: welcome.php");
  }else {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
     }
      }
   ?>
  <html>

  <head>
  <title>Login Page</title>

     <style type = "text/css">
      body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     label {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     .box {
        border:#666666 solid 1px;
     }
       </style>

   </head>

      <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">

  <div align = "center">
     <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
        <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; 
      padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

         <div style = "margin:30px">

           <form action = "" method = "post">
              <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = 
      "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
              <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = 
     "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
              <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
           </form>

           <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px"><? 
    php echo $error; ?></div>

        </div>

        </div>

         </div>

       </body>
  </html>
```

welcome.php

```
  <?php
   include_once 'session.php';

   ?>
  <html>

 <head>
  <title>Welcome </title>
  </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1> 
  <h2><a href = "logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
  </body>

   </html>
```

logout.php

```
     <?php
     session_start();

     if(session_destroy()) {
     header("Location: login.php");
      }
     ?>
```

session.php

```
    <?php
   include_once 'connect.php';
    session_start();

  $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

      $ses_sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select username from users where username = 
   '$user_check' ");

     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     $login_session = $row['username'];

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
  header("location:login.php");
   }
   ?>
```

connect.php

```
      <?php


 $databaseHost = 'localhost';
   $databaseName = 'amith';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
 $databasePassword = '';

   $mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, 
    $databasePassword, $databaseName);

  ?>
```

I'm creating a simple php registration form and a login form. 
    I have completed the registration form and thats working well, but now after 
    completing the registration form and later when they try to login to their page it should get logged in successfully
     but I'm unable to get this desired result, even tough i have the same username and same password 
     in the databse while registering but still when i try to login  with those username and password 
     i'm unable to login please can any one guide me what changes I should do to the above code 
    so that to obtain my result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are inserting password with `password_hash()` during registration.then you need to do verify the password with `password_verify()` .
use like this for check password matched or not

```
if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
    // If the password inputs matched the hashed password in the database
    // Do something, you know... log them in.
}
```

your login code

```
    <?php
   include_once 'connect.php';
 session_start();

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   // username and password sent from form 

   $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['username']);
   $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']); 

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' ";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $hashed_password=$row['password'];
  if(password_verify($mypassword, $hashed_password)) {

     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

     header("location: welcome.php");
     exit();
}    
  else 
  {
     $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
   ?>
```

Use prepared statement. because your code is open to sql injection attack.

Comment: same invalid username or  password its showing even tough i used same username or password

Comment: could you give me table schema i will try

Comment: ya sure i will paste it

Comment: i have used database name as amith

CREATE TABLE users (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255),
    email int,
    name int,
    Date_of_birth int,
    department varchar(255),
    age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169978/discussion-between-rahul-shrivastava-and-pooja-patil).

Comment: thanks alot sir ur suggestion really really helped me lot, thank you once again

Comment: glad to help you hahaha